# Filtering Data In PowerPivot on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerpivot

When viewing a PowerPivot workbook natively all is well. However when I save it to Sharepoint and view it via a browser, I find that the option to filter data by typing in a value is no longer present. (All there is is an extremely  LONG list of values which must be scrolled through and checked.) Being able to type in a value to search on is rather crucial feature when one wants to filter on a row where there may be thousands (or more) distinct values. Using a slicer or the standard filter drop-down in this case is pretty unworkable! Is there no way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a co-worker who could answer this question -- it was "hidden in plain sight". Instead of selecting 'Filter...' from a column header drop-down, select 'Label Filters' (used for text values) and then 'Begins with' from the secondary pop-up menu, and then you can type in the beginning of the string you are searching for. Silly me I thought 'Label Filters' had something to do with Labels, not text values.